# How to add one to value of EditText in Android

Tags: android, int

I am trying to get the string from an EditText and add 1 to the value on a button click but instead of doing 1+1 and setting it to 2, it outputs to the EditText 1111 and so on. I need some help getting the math working. Thanks in advance!

```
int rentPrice = 0;

int peopleCount = 0;

rentPrice = Integer.parseInt(mRentPriceText.getText().toString());

mybutton.setOnClickListent(new OnClickListener(){
    mRentPriceText.setText(rentPrice+1);
}
```

Comment: Try this way :   mRentPriceText.setText(String.valueOf((rentPrice+1)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like  this:

```
int rentPrice = 0;

int peopleCount = 0;



mybutton.setOnClickListent(new OnClickListener(){
rentPrice = Integer.parseInt(mRentPriceText.getText().toString());
int out = rentPrice+1;
    mRentPriceText.setText(String.valueOf(out));//Convert out to string
}
```

Answer (score 4):

String actually concats 1. so "1"+"1"="11".

So you have to first convert it to int and add 1 and then reconvert it to String and set it to EditText.

So change this line

```
mRentPriceText.setText(rentPrice+1);
```

to

mRentPriceText.setText(Integer.toString(rentPrice+1));

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
int temp = 0;
int rentPrice = 0;

int peopleCount = 0;

rentPrice = Integer.parseInt(mRentPriceText.getText().toString());
temp =rentPrice+1
mybutton.setOnClickListent(new OnClickListener(){
    mRentPriceText.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you gave int value as set text then it will find some string resource so cast int to string and use inner () add +1 to rentPrice :

```
mRentPriceText.setText(String.valueOf((rentPrice+1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing mTextview.setText(someInteger) you are more likely to get the below exception

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1134)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4940)
       2
```

because the TextView.setText(int) makes android think that you might be referring to some `R.string.some_string` . So wrap up your calculation work in the String as String.valueOf("some calculation")

Also I have some **Tip** for you

don't use toString() in line `rentPrice = Integer.parseInt(mRentPriceText.getText().toString());` otherwise you would more likely get some time `NullPointerException`

Instead always go with

rentPrice = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mRentPriceText.getText()));